# Webdriver.io - videos from video-reporter are not generated properly (cannot be opened)

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

I am new to werbdiver.io and I was looking for best reporter. Allure reports are working fine for me after some configuration, but video reporter doesn't.

Everytime a test fails, something like a video trace is created, but I cannot play the video itself (it has just 150kb). The video is available also in allure report, naturally I cannot play it.

I am sending my config:

reporters: [  
[video, {  
saveAllVideos: false,  
videoSlowdownMultiplier: 3,  
videoRenderTimeout: 5,  
outputDir: './allure-results'  
}],  
['allure', {  
outputDir: './allure-results',  
disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,  
disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: true,  
}],  
],

This is what I see as error (I guess the first line is important, I don't understand it as folder is existing):

[0-0] 2021-12-02T13:49:43.848Z ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\allure-results\My-Login-application--should-login-with-valid-credentials--CHROME--2021-12-02--14-49-22-485.mp4'  
[0-0]     at Object.statSync (fs.js:1131:3)  
[0-0]     at Object.statSync (C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:312:16)  
[0-0]     at C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\src\helpers.js:120:70  
[0-0]     at Array.map ()  
[0-0]     at Object.waitForVideosToBeWritten
(C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\src\helpers.js:120:33)  
[0-0]     at Video.onExit (C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\src\index.js:217:13)  
[0-0]     at process. (C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\node_modules\wdio-video-reporter\src\index.js:83:44)  
[0-0]     at process.emit (events.js:412:35)  
[0-0]     at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)  
[0-0]     at process.emit (C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\node_modules@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:527:35)  
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - C:\Data\Workspaces\webdriver\davinci-web-test\test\specs\example.ts  
2021-12-02T13:49:43.878Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:25

Comment: Not familiar with this recorder but if your session is failing to launch then it makes sense there will be not a playable video I think.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the output directory from the video reporter option :

```
 reporters: [
    ['video', {
      saveAllVideos: false,       // If true, also saves videos for successful test cases
      videoSlowdownMultiplier: 3, // Higher to get slower videos, lower for faster videos [Value 1-100]
    }],
    ['allure', {
      outputDir: './_results_/allure-raw',
      disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
      disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: true,
    }],
  ],
```

and generate allure report as :

`allure generate ./_results_/allure-raw`